# I am stuck on how to split up the file, then average it for each three years

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, average

I am trying to convert it from this below:

1997      5.12

1998    0.26

1999    2.41

2000    0.88

2001    0.79

2002    5.94

```
outputFile = open('myOutput03.txt', 'w')
inputFile = open('myInput03.txt', 'r')
content = inputFile.readlines()
k = 0
    for line in content:
         k = k + 1
         line = content.split()
         if k == 1:

         if k == 3:
         k = 0

 1997-1999 2.5966666667
 2002-2002 2.5366666667
```

To this above.

I am trying to provide a three-year average rainfall as output written in a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming Python based upon the syntax in what you posted, so I tried this out in Python 2.7:

```
import sys

data = []
with open('myInput03.txt', 'r') as myInput:
  for line in myInput:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line: continue
    try:
      (year, rainfall) = line.split()
      data.append((int(year), float(rainfall)))
    except ValueError:
      sys.stderr.write("Possible malformed line '%s'- skipping" % line)
      continue

dataSize = len(data)
if dataSize < 3:
  sys.stderr.write("Not enough data to compute 3 year average")
  sys.exit(1)

with open('myOutput03.txt', 'w') as myOutput:
  for i in xrange(2, dataSize):
    rainfallTotal = 0.0
    mySlice = data[i-2:i+1]
    for (year, rainfall) in mySlice: rainfallTotal += rainfall
    (firstYear, lastYear) = [data[j][0] for j in (i-2, i)]
    myOutput.write("%d-%d %f\n" % (firstYear, lastYear, rainfallTotal/len(mySlice)))
```

This will compute rolling averages for all three year periods - for instance, my output using your input was this:

```
1997-1999 2.596667
1998-2000 1.183333
1999-2001 1.360000
2000-2002 2.536667
```

You may need to modify it in case you don't want those middle periods to be computed.